# How to exit Haxe/OpenFL program?

Tags: haxe, openfl, haxeflixel, nme

I am making a game using Haxe, OpenFL (Formerly NME) and HaxeFlixel.

However, problem is, I can't seem to find a good way to make a Flixel button that will shutdown the game when pressed. I was planning to make a "quit" button on the main menu.

Is there any simple method to do so or is it impossible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on the compilation target: I'm going to assume you're compiling to CPP (Windows EXE). In which case you should just be able to use the following:

```
import flash.system.System; // Or nme.system.System if you're using NME

...

// in your FlxButton callback:
System.exit(0);
```

I can't test right now so I don't know what effect this would have in Flash (i.e. you may have to wrap it in a conditional compilation flag for cpp), but I do know that it won't work for iOS.

Comment: Just tested it on both Flash and Windows build settings, works on both. I do not plan to compile for iOS, so it's good enough for me :)