# Is there some kind of exit statement in Haxe?

Tags: haxe

Is there some kind of exit statement in haxe? Like

```
import sys
sys.exit(0)
```

in Python or

```
System.exit(0);
```

in Java?

P.S.: Only need this for sys targets ...

Comment: [Does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491958/how-to-exit-haxe-openfl-program)? (disclaimer: I don't know that language)

Comment: @user202729 Yes and no, Haxe code can get cross-compiled into multiple languages, like neko, javascript, python, ... . The answer you provided does only work, if the code gets cross-compiled into the flash language ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Sys.exit(code)` in sys targets (cpp, cs, hl, java, lua, macro, neko, php, python).

https://api.haxe.org/Sys.html#exit

And for Flash target: `flash.system.System.exit(code)`
https://api.haxe.org/flash/system/System.html#exit